# Docker : build an image

Tags: docker

My container doesn't want to start again (`Couldn't run auplink before unmount /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/6a32630585211a651c406794ad20e7965c59318ea65d485855b8d7925b9f6e40 segmentation fault (core dumped)`).

So, I will commit it to make another image. But commit doesn't work too (dockerd process works at 100%, but nothing after 8 hours).

So, I can export and I think I have my original image : can I "rebuild" an image from original and the export (to have my modifications) OR from layers (I think my mount point, in `/var/lib/aufs/docker/mnt`, is corrupt) ?

Thanks

Comment: How do you know that your container *doesn't want* to start again? What did he tell you?

Comment: @sam - Very confusing question! You should check `docker logs` when you thought docker is not working to check the reason behind the broke down. 
To answer your rebuild corrupt image. I would suggest, you should use `dockerfile` or if you have more than one application depending one each other then use docker-compose.yml to manage your images and containers.

Comment: @Robert : When I check the mnt directory, this one (/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/6a32...) is the only with a file "core" (I don't know if there is a link). I have just only 1 container.

Comment: do you see something doing this? `docker diff <your-container-id>`

Comment: @Robert At this time, nothing (the command is "running", but nothing, like a `docker commit <my-container-id>` for me)

Comment: If you see nothing, either your docker is broken or your container has no changed anything on top of its image.

Comment: @Robert Finally, I make a new container (from a previous version) and, as I make a mount point, I lost nothing. I don't know really what happens, but I think the container has an error (in a container file). Thanks

Comment: Oh.. ok, nice then. You're welcome